# Can I prevent a neighbor from building a fence against my house?

Tags: fence

I live in a townhouse community, and the side of my house acts as a fence for my neighbor's yard. He wants to now put a fence next to my house so he doesn't have to look at the side of it. I have concerns regarding termites, rats and mold etc. living in the tiny area between. The side of my house is the property line. Do I even have a say so?

[image]

Comment: So up to the roof line?

Comment: Your deed, lease, HOA contract, and other legal documents will define what rights you and your neighbor have.  In a townhouse community the area around the property line is often not strictly "owned" by you, or if it is, what you may do there is well defined.  I would be surprised if your neighbor could do something that prevents you from gaining access to perform maintenance on your house wall.  But it's possible.

Comment: If your neighbor allowed you to take this picture you must have a reasonable working relationship.  Maybe you could find a compromise, such as allowing them to  paint your siding to their liking, or to attach inorganic fence panels or trellis directly to your wall without touching the ground, or to plant some bushes a suitable distance away from your wall.

Comment: Adding a fence will have minimal impact on the termite, rat or mold population. The real issue is what happens to the neighbor's fence when you need to do some repairs to your siding. You'll have to tear it down.

Comment: As you can't see it, would you be upset if your neighbour decorated the wall up to the height of the existing fence? Perhaps with some brown paint that pretty much matches. It would be faster and cheaper for him, and give some weatherproofing to the surface for you.

Comment: Is that wall to your house right on the property line?

Comment: Moving the fence onto your property? But the fence needs to be straight and now how much do you loose? I would not worry about mice, termites etc as the fence should not be in contact with the home. I am used to small lots like this requirement to have good neighbor fences, every other fence plank on the other side. What do you have to look at?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a legal or local code issue.

Comment: I think OP's concern is that if the fence is a few inches from the wall, leaves and crud will accumulate in the gap, will harbor moisture and rot and attract nesting.

Comment: Voting to close also because answers to the question as currently asked will inevitably just speculate on terms of ownership.  Christine you can edit and reopen the question making it more specifically about how to build something there, once you know what's allowed and what you and your neighbor can agree on.

Comment: Yes, this is a legal question, and the buzzword here is "HOA" or Home Owners Association.  They have neighborhood rules about what can be done, and they are more powerful than a city ordinance.  You can use their force to limit your neighbor's ability to do anything untoward.

Answer (score 3):

It's reasonable to be concerned about accessibility of your building for inspection, maintenance, and upkeep and cleanliness reasons. It's almost certain that you personally do not have a "say so" in whether or not the neighbor can construct a fence here, but I think it's very likely that somewhere there is language that restricts him doing it. The onus is on you to find that language and then persuade the local government (or the HOA, if applicable) to step in and enforce it.

Municipal zoning rules ("ordinances" or "codes") often impose minimum "setback" requirements. A setback is the minimum distance separating a building from the edges of the property upon which it is built. You have what is called a "zero lot line home." This term alludes to there being a "zero setback" on one of the lot lines, meaning the house is built on or very near the property line. Some high density communities are designed with this feature to balance the need for adequate space between buildings with the need for that space to be allocated in a usable way (think of fire or maintenance access to the rear yard).

Because zero setback is an exception to the norm it would be expected that, in granting permission for the development, the zoning authority (a city, probably) would impose conditions -- for example, that a fence adjacent to a building would be prohibited.

You're going to have to do your own research. Here are several things to look for. Start with whichever is easiest for you to access. Read the material yourself: helpful people may summarize for you what they think these materials say, but chances are they've never read the materials with the same question in mind as you have now. They might be surprised by what you find!

- City zoning code. Look for regulations applicable to zero lot line construction. Look for regulations on fencing too; there may be requirements for minimum space between parallel fences or fences parallel to buildings.
- The complete plat map of the community. There may be several pages. The map may be included in your home mortgage paperwork, and should also be available through the county recorder's office. Pay attention to which areas of land are common area owned by the HOA and which areas are privately owned by homeowners. Read all the blocks of notes on every page - there can be interesting and important details hidden in the fine print.
- Find out whether there was any conditional use permit or site plan issued for the community, and if so what are its conditions. A government records request through the city recorder's office may be the mechanism for obtaining this info.

Comment: Good point on checking with the County Recorder, the association documents are probably also recorded.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you probably do not have a say so, the association has the ultimate say so. That's one of the positive/negative things about having a condo/townhouse association. There should be bylaws or some sort of association documents that allow/restrict any sort of structure being placed or built. They also may not allow you to change colors, doors, garage doors exterior lights or place plantings. One positive is someone with poor decorating ideas can't make changes and lower the value of everyone else's unit. One of the negatives is if you want to do something that you think is an improvement it may not be allowed. Sometimes owners may try to get special permission from the board for something that is not allowed and if it affects you then you may have a say so.

Comment: I would say the OP has say so, the unit belongs to the OP the HOA has rules or covenants, but they can not intrude on a property.